# Hibernate adding member variable name to generated SQL for a joinColumn on SecondaryTable

Tags: java, spring, hibernate

I have an entity with these tables:

```
@Entity
@Table(name = "PM_ADJ_MULTI_YR_DETAILS")
@SecondaryTables(
{
@SecondaryTable(name = "PM_RPT_MASTER",   pkJoinColumns = @PrimaryKeyJoinColumn(name = "INCTV_APP_SAK")),
@SecondaryTable(name = "PM_INCTV_APP",    pkJoinColumns = @PrimaryKeyJoinColumn(name = "INCTV_APP_SAK")),
@SecondaryTable(name = "PM_ADJ_MULTI_YR", pkJoinColumns = @PrimaryKeyJoinColumn(name = "MULTI_YR_ADJ_SAK"))
}
)
```

On this entity I have a member variable as follows:

```
@ManyToOne
@JoinColumn(name = "MMIS4_IND", table = "PM_ADJ_MULTI_YR")
private MultiYrAdjMmis4Ind mmis4Ind;
```

Hibernate is adding the member variable name to the generated SQL as follows:

```
AND t1.MMIS4IND_MMIS4_IND = t4.MMIS4_IND(+)
```

This should be:

```
AND t1.MMIS4_IND = t4.MMIS4_IND(+)
```

We're using javax.persistence-2.0.0.jar and Spring 3.0.2.

Answer (score 0):

FYI: Found a solution/workaround for this problem at: https://issues.apache.org/jira/browse/OPENJPA-2157?jql=text%20~%20%22joinColumn%20on%20secondarytable%22

Apparently it is known problem with OpenJPA (we're using OpenJPA v2.0.0).

For the solution/workaround you simply need to change the version of persistence specified in the persistence.xml (v2.0 can't handle it but v1.0 can).

Change this:
http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/persistence/persistence_***2_0***.xsd">

To:
http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/persistence/persistence_***1_0***.xsd">